# Замена или лечение функции pow в Linux. C

Tags: c, linux

Приветствую кодеры.

Есть вопросик. Каким образом, под линем лечится следующая беда.

Вот код, базовая лаба 1го курса.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   int i,N; float y,S;
printf("Введи N:\n");
scanf("%d",&N);
S=0;
for(i=1; i<=N; i++);
S+=(i+pow(2,i));
y=S;
printf("y=%f",y);
return 0;

 }
```

и тут, наш любимый gcc выдает такую бяку "1.1.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `pow'". Пишу в программке Geany, хотя разницы где писать не вижу. Как это вылечить, ну или заменить?

Comment: Да, и ещё, если кто-нибудь знает пособия по компьютерной графике (программирование всяких полосочек-квадратиков) и может дать линк, то думаю поможет не мне одному.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Надо включить заголовок math.h
2. При компиляции надо подключать библиотеку libm.so. В строке это выглядит так

   gcc progtext.c -o prog -lm

Comment: с инклудами проблем нет, я их просто не запостил) а как это прикрутить в программу? Не самое удобное, когда каждый код надо в терминале фиксить... Если это вообще реально

Comment: В geany не работал, но там наверняка есть какой-то пунктик меню, где можно указать подключаемые библиотеки или передаваемые компилятору параметры. Покопайся.

Comment: да покопал, синтаксис терминала пока не очень понял, как его интегрировать в прогу...

Comment: Посмотрел, как внедрить в Geany. Пункт меню Сборка->Установить команды сборки. Там в строке "Сборка" дописать -lm и ОК.

Comment: Хм, работает... Зря я команды полностью писал видать. Премногоблагодарен за помощь

Comment: Вообще, если хотите далее писать под линь, осваивайте командную строку. Там нет ничего сложного. А для программиста достаточно знать около десятка команд.

Comment: Да терминальные комманды я знаю, а вот компилятора нет. Библиотек много, а это всёж сложновато

Comment: Как это нет компилятора? Какой дистрибутив?

Answer (score 2):

не парься. Вместо pow используй битовое смещение:
1<<i вместо pow(2,i). Результат тот же, а вычислительная сложность меньше.

Comment: 1. битовый сдвиг умножает/делит на 2, а не возводит в степень (хотя в данном случае это все равно, однако нужно смотреть в будущее)
2. он работает только для целочисленных типов.
3. человек учится и ему нужно научиться работать с математической библиотекой.

Comment: Да дело в том, что такие решения преподаватели не примут) у нас как церковь - либо по лекции либо никак... Но за совет благодарю